# how to change identity column based on user insertion

Tags: sql-server

I have

```
table test (id int identity (1,1) , name varchar)
```

column name is in (group1,or group2, or group 3) what we want is when a user insert a   specific group the id column reseed to be changed. so each name group has a specific   identity seed appreciate your help

```
required results  
-----------------------
id     | name 
----------------------
1000   | group1               
1001   | group1   
2000   | group2   
2001   | group2    
3000   | group3   
3001   | group3   
3003   | group3
```

Comment: This seems like a major design flaw. Do you really want to be reseeding these constantly? If so what's the point of having the constraint in the first place. Also why does it matter what value the ID is in the first place. Is the ID called elsewhere? If so you will have to re-seed all over the database. Part of the benefit of an ID is you don't care what the value is. It just needs to link tables together.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should not set the auto-increment of the table. Leave this logic in your application, and configure that group 1, would have Ids available from say for example 1-1000. This obviously could cause problems when you run out of Ids for group 1 - but this type of logic should be handled at an application layer.